# Why SendMessage doesn't work when window dont have focus?

Tags: c++

I have a problem with the sendmessage command, I try to send a message to the window that I press the d key and it starts with a problem. When the window is active, there is no problem, but when there is no focus, it does not respond to the command, someone has an idea what could be the problem or where can I start looking for solutions?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

HWND window;

int main(){
    window= FindWindowEx(0, 0, "AAAA", 0);

    cout << "TEST" << endl;
    SendMessage(window, WM_KEYDOWN, 0x44, 0x00200001);
    Sleep(4000);
    SendMessage(window, WM_KEYUP, 0x44, 0xC0200001);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [You can't simulate keyboard input with PostMessage](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050530-11/?p=35513) (and SendMessage, too)

Comment: Ok, so how i can to do it? I was see many threads on forum and i can't find answer on my question.